# What numerical method should i use for the given example?

Tags: scilab

PROBLEM: We have partial difference equation u(t): du/dt=sin(t); u(0)=0.

What numerical method should I use to solve the equation, how would i write an algorithm for u(1)?

I thought I could try finite difference method but I could use some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a look at the ode function